# Test on URL in header.php

Tags: php, url, header

I'm trying to put different breadcrumb following the URL so I put that code at the end of my `header.php` file:

```
<div class="fil_ariane">

<?php 
$url= $_SERVER['Query_String'];
if(strpos($url, 'property')){
    echo'<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">< Retour</a>';
}else{
if ( function_exists( 'yoast_breadcrumb' ) ) {
    yoast_breadcrumb();

}} ?>

</div>
```

Everything is working except the echo

Any Idea ?

Comment: What does that mean it doesnt work anymore. What errors?

Comment: I forgot to paste it but I close the div after ?>

Comment: What is the error and what is inside your yoast_breadcrumb();() function?

Comment: The website page is blanck

Comment: Switch on error_reporting

Comment: yoast_breadcrum function is from a wordpress plugin and it works well.
At the begenning the code that works is only
 <div class="fil_ariane">

<?php if ( function_exists( 'yoast_breadcrumb' ) ) {

 yoast_breadcrumb();

} ?>

</div>

Comment: @Barou Are you kidding? How can you develop with the error reporting turned off? You should have even notices enabled for a development.

Comment: `echo'<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">< Retour</a>'` <-- missing closing `;`. Also use the entity for `<`, `&#60;`.

Comment: The error I get is
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

But nothing more specific

Comment: BTW If you want to output a character like "<" (less than) as a text, which has a special meaning in HTML, you should use an entity (&lt;).

Comment: I added ; but its still doesn't work

Comment: Whats the error log show? What does `yoast_breadcrumb` have/do? You also should update your question with what you now have.

Comment: The error log shows an error 500 but I don't understand why

yoast_bread crumb is a function from wordpress plugin. I sur error is not due to it because original code that works is 
<div class="fil_ariane">

<?php if ( function_exists( 'yoast_breadcrumb' ) ) {

 yoast_breadcrumb();

} ?>

</div> 

Mine is actually
 <div class="fil_ariane">

<?php 
$url= $_SERVER['Query_String'];
if(strpos($url, 'property')){
 echo'<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">< Retour</a>';
}else{
if ( function_exists( 'yoast_breadcrumb' ) ) {
 yoast_breadcrumb();

}} ?>

</div>

Comment: I edited question that's more readable ;)

Comment: Must be something else on that page. That code works, https://eval.in/447834.

Comment: OK It's now working :)
In fact Almost :
The echo does'nt work

I edited the Question

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct, but you missed semicolon after the echo. If your code is same you pasted then that might be a problem.

Comment: I added the semicolon but it's not better :(
If you wanna see
http://www.preprod.senior-conseil-immobilier.com/nos-offres-immobilieres-en-residence-senior/